# Mapping drive on a remote machine in powershell

Tags: powershell, mapping, net-use

I am working on a remote machine from my desktop and I have the following script :

> Invoke-Command -computername $name -authentification default
>   -credential $creds1 
>   -scriptblock {net use \share $password2 /user:otherdomain\otheruser}

Then I get A specified logon session does not exist. It may have already been terminated. This thing is frustrating because if I run `net use \\share $password2 /user:otherdomain\otheruser` directly on the remote machine it works perfectly. Is there a workaround or did I miss something ?

Comment: I have found by adding net session to my remote script that there is no entry. Does someone know how to manually add one ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable `$password2` into the script block, otherwise its value will be empty:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $name ... -ScriptBlock {
  net use \\host\share $args[0] /user:otherdomain\otheruser
} -ArgumentList $password2
```